# How to make the tablix in .rdlc reports start from the right and expand to the left?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm working on a project (Windows Forms) and have a .rdlc report with several columns. The columns are displayed perfectly from right to left when all columns are visible, but when some columns are hidden, a blank space is left from the right for each hidden column. In other words, every hidden column has invisible content but its position is still there. I tried almost every property that may affect both the position or the direction of how the report should be displayed but it changed nothing for me. The report viewer tool is contained in a panel.

[image: When all columns are displayed:]

[image: When some columns are hidden]

Comment: As you can see in your second image, the hidden columns do not occupy space, so everything works like expected. I guess that you want the report header to shrink also, but it won't, as it has nothing to do with the table in the body. You might want to check the "RightToLeft" property in the ReportViewer.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't change anything.